# Populating Material-UI DataGrid from MongoDB failing for unique ID not found

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, material-ui

Error: Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without in the rows prop is what I am seeing when I call the table.

Here is how I have the table defined.

```
const columns = [
  { field: "_id", hide: true },
  { field: "user", headerName: "User", width: 70 },
  { field: "fromaddress", headerName: "Sender", width: 70 },
  { field: "dkimSpfChk", headerName: "DKIM/SPF", width: 70 },
  { field: "replySenderMismatch", headerName: "Reply MisMatch", width: 70 },
  { field: "riskywordchk", headerName: "Risky Word", width: 70 },
  { field: "domainagechk", headerName: "Sender Domain Age", width: 70 },
  { field: "attachmentChk", headerName: "Attachments", width: 70 },
  { field: "riskyLinkAge", headerName: "Body Link Age", width: 70 },
  { field: "riskyLinkTypo", headerName: "Link Typosquatting", width: 70 },
  {
    field: "senderTypoSquatting",
    headerName: "Sender TypoSquatting",
    width: 70,
  }
];
```

I get the data from my api and then populate in the row

```
 useEffect(() => {
    var apiurl = "http://localhost:5000/adminportal/highRiskEmails";
    axios
      .get(apiurl)
      .then((response) => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoaded(true);
        setRowData(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here is the datagrid

```
return (
  <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={rowData}
      columns={columns}
      id="_id"
      pageSize={15}
      checkboxSelection
    />
  </div>
);
```

I know the _id field is unique from Mongo so wondering what I am missing. Do I have to define that the id field is not id but _id?

thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can now use the `getRowId` property that accepts a function to specify which property on each row should be considered the id.

In the OP's case, you could do: `getRowId={(row) => row._id}`

Reference: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/pull/972

Comment: I think this is the most elegant solution here. Simple and neat

Comment: Where do you put this line : getRowId={(row) => row._id}  ?

Could you give some sample code please? Thanks!

Comment: @Ezani, it's added to the DataGrid component as a prop just like `columns` or `rows`

Comment: Do I put it here :

const rows [
getRowId={(row) => row._id}
]

or here:

return( 
  <div style={{ height: 700, width: '100%' }}>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%' }}>
        <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>

            <ReactDataGrid 
              columns={columns}
              rows={rowData}
              //id="_id"
              id ={(row) => row._id}  <---------------------
              pageSize={15}
            />

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
);

Comment: @Ezani, In your example: `<ReactDataGrid columns={columns} rows={rowData} getRowId ={(row) => row._id} />`

Comment: Hey  @BenStickley thanks a million! Really thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome @Ezani! Please upvote if it worked for you :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I just put the option **{ virtuals: true }** in my schema:

```
const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    lastName: String,
    firstName: String,
    nickname: String,
}, opts);
```

So when i try to query, the field **"id"** is added. Something like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "602fc7aba323ec87f00f9c76",
        "lastName": "Targaryen",
        "firstName": "Daenerys",
        "nickname": "",
        "__v": 0,
        **"id": "602fc7aba323ec87f00f9c76"**
    }
]
```

Comment: This should be used with @Morgan Smith's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65077424/1831518

Answer (score 2):

I was having a hard time with this too, turns out you can make virtual ids

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html

Comment: while this one way to go about it I think @Ben Stickley 's answer is more appropriate in this context

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem on my DataGrid component and I solved it with math.random() as an id >> `<DataGrid id={Math.random()} />`

Comment: when i did this i got an error that said "id isn't a property for datagrid"

Comment: I have the same issue as Morgan Smith

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to create unable keys. Just add an actual `id` into the row records.

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the back-end i changed the return object json

```
id_inspeccion
```

to

```
id
```

So in the frontend when the table gets the data, it will associate "id" and it will automatically work